# Set R plots x axis to show at y=0

Tags: r, plot

Usually when I plot some R line plot and set `ylim=c(0,some_value)`, there is small space between the x axis and y=0.

I would like the y axis to show exactly at y=0 so points (x,0) will be plotted on the y axis (and not above).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You probably want the graphical parameters `xaxs` and `yaxs` with style "i":

```
plot(1:10, rnorm(10), ylim=c(0,10), yaxs="i")
```

See `?par`:

> **xaxs**: The style of axis interval
>   calculation to be used for the x-axis.
>   Possible values are "r", "i", "e",
>   "s", "d". The styles are generally
>   controlled by the range of data or
>   xlim, if given. Style "r" (regular)
>   first extends the data range by 4
>   percent at each end and then finds an
>   axis with pretty labels that fits
>   within the extended range. Style "i"
>   (internal) just finds an axis with
>   pretty labels that fits within the
>   original data range. Style "s"
>   (standard) finds an axis with pretty
>   labels within which the original data
>   range fits. Style "e" (extended) is
>   like style "s", except that it is also
>   ensures that there is room for
>   plotting symbols within the bounding
>   box. Style "d" (direct) specifies that
>   the current axis should be used on
>   subsequent plots. (Only "r" and "i"
>   styles are currently implemented)
>
> **yaxs**: The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the y-axis.
>   See *xaxs* above.

Comment: Note that, quote: "Only "r" and "i" styles have been implemented in R." I guess this means that "e", "s", and "d" are available in S only (what else could it mean?) Anyhow, unfortunately, these other ones are not available in R.

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to disable the axis plotting in plot using `axes=F` and then put the axes in separately using the axis command, with the `pos` option controlling the axis spacing.

```
plot(1:10, runif(10), ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,10),axes=F)
     axis(1, pos=0)
     axis(2, pos=0)
```