# how to make coordinates not to cross at `O` in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In R, coordinates cross not at `O` by default. I mean that there is a tiny space before 0.
When code `xaxs="i", yaxs="i"`, the plot will cross at `O`. [[1]set-r-plots-x-axis-to-show-at-y-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422203/set-r-plots-x-axis-to-show-at-y-0),
 [[2]The "i" is an abbreviation for internal](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/120/Notes/ch03.pdf)

So, is there an alternative way like `xaxs` to let the plot not to cross at `O` in gnuplot?

Answer (score 1):

In gnuplot you can set the range for the x axis using `set xrange` and similarly for the y axis. If you want the axes to start a little before 0 you can try

```
set xrange [-0.5:]
set yrange [-0.5:]
```